# Permanent REST web service url with many and long parameters

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest, jersey-2.0

Since I found it very difficult to explain my problem in the heading I'm going to explain it a little further:
I want to /I'm writing a JAX-RS web service (Jersey/Servlet3.0) and the corresponding JS library for a geographic use case. The input of the web service are two lists (source & target points) of geographic points (latitude, longitude) and each point having a list of parameters. Since there is basically no limit on the number of points I don't know how to combine the URL length limit and the unlimitedness of the parameter list.

Here are the restrictions again:

1. Easy to share URL (so POST probably wont quite cut it?) for social media sharing and of course easy debugging
2. An example configuration can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/gerbsen/8271485) please note that there can be nested sets of parameters (point 1 has parameters of it's own)
3. Needs to able to be integrated in external website (with bookmarkable url)
4. Not all of the parameters are mandatory, what is the best way to deal with defaults/missing values?

What I thought of so far is:

- create a boatload of parameters
- jsonify the configuration and send it to server via url parameter

But I don't really like these options. Am I missing something?
Sorry for this rather vague question.
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok to your points

1. for easy sharing why not just implement a tinyURl or bit.ly style sharing system - obviously you can't have both an easy to pass-in url (a URL that makes it easy to give the server detailed information) that is easy to share (human friendly and short) - but you could very easily save the results (or inputs and calculate each time) to a database and link that to a tinyURl.

   as an aside POST will be the only way to handle this due to the amount of data.
2. Just pass as JSON - easy to nest paramaeters that way
3. Don't quite get this part - for an external site to use this they could post the data and you return the answers - or using point 1 method of 'tinyurl / bit.ly style system it could call this in an iframe?
4. You would deal with missing parameters / defaults at server side - create a function for each parameter - if parameter is expected then throw error - if parameter has a default include this in your function and if parameter is not included then don't run the function.

Hope that makes sense?